# Access previous value of a vector in sapply

Tags: sapply

I wish to write an `sapply` version of the following code.  As you can see the `for` code replaces the value at position `i` with a mean of the values at positions `i-1`  and `i+1`.  How do i do this with an `sapply`?

```
  test <- c(1:length(x))
  if(length(which(x > mean(x) + sd(x)*3)) > 0){
    for (i in 1:length(x)) {
      if(x[i] > mean(x) + sd(x)*3){
        x[i] <- mean(x[i-1], x[i+1])
      }
      else{
        x[i] <- x[i]
      }
    }
  }
  else{
    test <- x
  }
```

In order to generate a suitable (i.e., non-normal) test vector, I use the `rstable` function from the `StableEstim` package.

```
x <- rstable(100, alpha = 1.48, beta = 0.99, gamma = 0.27, delta = 3.36)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help anyone else but I found a way to make my code less computationally intensive without using `sapply`:

```
spiker <- function(x){
  l <- c(which(x > mean(x) + sd(x)*3), which(x < mean(x) - sd(x)*3))
  if(length(l) > 0){
    for (i in l) {
     x[i] <- mean(x[i-1], x[i+1])
    }
    x <- x
    spiker(x)
  }
  else{
     x <<- x
  }
}
```

The only issue with this is if the first or last element in the vector `x` meets the 3 sd criteria, then the mean will not be computed.